# Higlight text in ActionScript

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need some library that will allow me to highlight multiple words in TextField (or TextArea). There is [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) library that has some Higlighter class but it doesn't work for multiline words (it has bug when it encounter End Of Line). Also there is another way [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/07/20/how-to-highlight-the-text-in-flex-with-full-source-code.html) but it also doesn't work for multiline words. So is there any other solution, or we are left to it ourselfs?

Comment: Have you tried to build it yourself?  Have you come across any specific problems?  I would expect that the Adobe text layout framework or an alternative such as TinyTLF should make this pretty easy.

Comment: Are you trying to select multiple words that are "touching" eachother, or separated by 1 or more words / white-space? I'm not sure highlighting of separate words is even possible, at least with the built in Flash selection methods available. Might have to make some custom tool that will "visually" present your words AS SELECTED, and keep track of the selection list yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the subject of highlighting was discussed in several posts in TLF forum:
http://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/tlf
FTQuest